# Can't get a csv file using fputcsv() and an array returned by pg_fetch_xxx()

Tags: php, fputcsv

I am trying to export a csv file with php, using an array returned by pg_fetch_array. But the csv file is empty.

If I write an array by hand, the csv is correct.
I tried to build an array from pg_fetch_all without success.

```
<?php
$listope = pg_fetch_array($marequete) ;

$fichier = fopen("export.csv", "w") ;

foreach ($listope as $line) {
    fputcsv($fichier, explode(',',$line));
}

fclose($fichier) ;
?>
```

I know that the problem is the `$listope` var which does not return a proper array but I can't find the solution.
Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont explode the array, the fputcsv() function does all that for you

So simply do

```
fputcsv($fichier, $line);
```

> Another thing, you only read one row from the result set, now that maybe because you only expect one row, but as you also code a loop,  if the query would generate more than one row try this, using `pg_fetch_all()`

```
$listope = pg_fetch_all($marequete) ;

$fichier = fopen("export.csv", "w") ;

foreach ($listope as $line) {
    fputcsv($fichier, $line);
}

fclose($fichier) ;
```

> Reference [The manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)

Comment: I was not that far...thank you. And Indeed I am expecting 0 or n results from the query.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are making this more complicated than necessary. [`pg_fetch_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-fetch-array.php) returns one row from your result-set, so it you want to save that in a csv file, you would only need:

```
$listope = pg_fetch_array($marequete) ;

$fichier = fopen("export.csv", "w") ;

fputcsv($fichier, $listope);
```

Comment: Interesting, how we have a slightly different way of looking at the same question :)